# Error en metodo Enumerable.Except de LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var vistaRecibos = (from r in ctx.RECIBOSPAGO_DETALLE_GENERAL
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      r.idrecibopago,
                                  });

                var vistaAsientos = (from a in ctx.ASIENTO_CONTABLE
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      a.idrecibopago,
                                  });

                vistaRecibos = vistaRecibos.Except(vistaAsientos);
```

El cual me da error:

> Error 71  Los argumentos de tipo para el método 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Except(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' no se pueden inferir a partir del uso. Intente especificar los argumentos de tipo explícitamente.  C:\Users\German\Desktop\SAM Administrativo\Leon\SAM1\Contabilidad\frmExportarAsientosContables.cs   461 36  sammayorazgo

E usado esta comparacion en otras soluciones y no me marca error (incluso la coma extra no causa conflictos, y si la quito, el problema sigue).

Alguien sabe como arreglarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifica tus lineas de esta forma

```
var vistaRecibos = from r in ctx.RECIBOSPAGO_DETALLE_GENERAL
                                  select r.idrecibopago;

var vistaAsientos = from a in ctx.ASIENTO_CONTABLE
                                  select a.idrecibopago;

vistaRecibos = vistaRecibos.Except(vistaAsientos);
```

No es necesario agregar la palabra **new {}** eso lo necesitarias si estuvieras mapeando a otro tipo de dato.

Comment: aun con esta correccion me sigue dando error:  `Error 27 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int?>' no contiene una definición para 'Except' y la mejor sobrecarga del método de extensión 'System.Linq.Queryable.Except<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' tiene algunos argumentos no válidos C:\Users\German\Desktop\SAM Administrativo\Leon\SAM1\Contabilidad\frmExportarAsientosContables.cs 455 36 sammayorazgo`

Comment: force a que la primer consulta devuelva int, eso funciono ya, gracias!

Comment: Alguno de los dos queries regresaba un int? y el otro int lo que los hacia incompatibles.